# linux "find rm" command also remove the root directory

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to remove all directories inside /mongo-backups directory which last modified 10 minute ago. but as I run the command it also remove the /mongo-backups directory

```
find /Users/ehsansarshar/Desktop/mongo-backups -type d -mmin -10 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-mindepth 1` to exclude the current directory:

```
find /whatever/dir -mindepth 1 -type d ......
```

Comment: can you explain more